# SAS array DO loop calculation within data step

Tags: arrays, sas, do-loops

I have the following data set:

```
data have;
    input x10 x22 x13 x64;
cards;
20 10 30 1
;
run;
```

I want to create four new columns called `log_x10`, `log_x22`, `log_x13`, `log_x64` which are the logs of the original columns.  I know this is probably a fairly straightforward array, loop process, but I'm fairly new to arrays and can't quite get the syntax.  Here is what I have:

```
data want;
    set have;
    array var[*] x: ;
    do j=1 to dim(var);
        logx[j]=log(var[j]);
    end;
run;
```

It won't always be four variables, sometimes less or more. I have the id numbers pulled into a macrolist `id=(10,22,13,64)` so can try to use something like that to name.

Ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to establish the length of your array at in order to declare your result array.  Fortunately you can load it into a macro variable with with short datastep.

```
data have;
    input x10 x22 x13 x64;
cards;
20 10 30 1
;
run;

data _null_;
    set have (obs=1);
    array vars[*] x: ;
    call symput('array_length',cats(dim(vars)));
run;

data want;
    length logx1-logx&array_length. 8;
    set have;
    array vars[*] x: ;
    array logvars[*] logx1-logx&array_length.;
    do j=1 to dim(vars);
        logvars[j]=log(vars[j]);
    end;
run;
```